# Xpath not finding elements past the first

Tags: python, lxml, xpath

I'm working on a scraper using xpath, but xpath seems inexplicably incapable of retreiving the information that I need.  I've been able to get the below code to print out the table element and all of its contents, but as soon as I try to go to the tbody or tr elements, it starts returning None.   You can see the url below as well.

I've used XPather in Firefox to confirm that the below is correct, but for some reason the path fails once put into Python.

```
url = 'http://www.arkleg.state.ar.us/assembly/2011/2011R/pages/CommitteeDetail.aspx?committeecode=000'

with self.urlopen(url) as page:
    page = lxml.html.fromstring(page)

    for tr in page.xpath('//table[@class="gridtable"]/tbody/tr'):
        print tr.xpath('string(td[1])')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox adds the implicit `tbody` inside the `table` element, but this doesn't exist in the source HTML for that page.  This XPATH should work to find all the `tr` tags:

```
for node in page.xpath('.//table[@class="gridtable"]/tr'):
```

Comment: Oof, would not have guessed that about FF adding implicit elements.  Thanks!

Comment: @IanWhalen: There are mandatory elements in (X)HTML wich are added by browsers to the DOM like `head` and `tbody`.